# any dynamic length two dimension structure in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Please guide me, are there any out of box data structures in C# that support dynamic length and two or more dimensions?

I tried to use a string array but length is an issue. I want some structure that can be built and support 2 dimensions, like some text and its value.

Please suggest solutions.

Comment: Dictionary<K,V>, Tuple<A,B,C,...> spring to mind. Type "System.Collections.Generic" and hit F1 to get an overview of the most common collection classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want key-value pairs you can use a `Hashtable` or `NameValueCollection`.

Answer (score 3):

How about a `List<List<T>>`?

First of all, "two or more dimensions" isn't all that specific.

Do you need 2? Or 3? Or more? What is "more" anyway?

Also, do you need a rectangular data set like a 2 dimensional array? Or do you need one that has different widths for different rows?

Also, your "some text and its value" suggests you're not really looking at a 2 dimensional data structure, but a 1 dimensional data structure, containing elements that have multiple values.

The difference here is that a 2 dimensional data structure would have the same type of elements in both dimensions, whereas the other can have different types of elements, like an int and a string.

So perhaps you need to tell us a bit more about what you need to store in that structure.

Otherwise, `List<List<T>>` it is.

Comment: HI, what about KeyValuePairs ?

Comment: What about them? You're still not very specific in what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking. There are many ways to use the generic collections to build 2-dimensional data structures. What is it that you really want?

If you're talking about text data that you want to split into lines, and those lines can be modified, then how about `List<StringBuilder>`? That will allow you to add and delete lines, and you can also modify the individual lines.